# MARIADB GALERA CLUSTR

Tags: cluster-computing, mariadb, galera

I have a working cluster with three nodes on 192.168.14 subnet
I wanted to add an external machine to cluster ip 78.3.157.x
External machine fails to join cluster with "failed to open gcom backend connection 110"
Is such a configuration actually possible and if so how

Comment: Have you looked at http://serverfault.com/? This question seems more appropriate for that community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a network level problem. The servers are not able to reach each other because you probably have some sort of non-transparent NAT device between the server. One of the IPs is public and the others are private.

Fix your networking layer so that all your nodes have full non-NAT:ed connectivity between each other. They do not need to be in the same subnet as long as the connectivity between them works in every direction.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. You are spot on with nat as I had to put rule in checkpoint to see external machine. Do you think I should dropping nat rule and add routes to machines